# How to show/hide (with animation if possible) a CheckBox within a LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I've been trawling the MSDN for hours now and can't find an example of how to show or hide a CheckBox within a list in Windows Phone 8. An example would be within the messaging application, where the user uses the Application Bar to press a 'multiple selection' button. This allows the user to select multiple messages.

I've came across some information about using Expression Blend and the `VisualStateManager` but for some reason it does not seem to be capable of applying state groups to a `LongListSelector`.

All I want to do is create a list exactly like one within the messaging application of Windows Phone 8? Any help would be much appreciated.

My XAML code thus far:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="albumList" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0, 12">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="albumArt" Grid.Column="0" Width="96" Height="96" Source="{Binding CoverAddress}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="12,0,0,0 " />
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,17" VerticalAlignment="Center" >                           
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumTitle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" FontSize="24"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArtistName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

[image: Before pressing Application Bar Button] [image]

Above are screenshots of the messaging application within Windows Phone 8. They show the change from a list to a multi-select list after having pressed a button within the Application Bar.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Have you tried anything with creating a template of the list, and adding a checkbox to said template?

Comment: @plast1K I've posted the XAML code used to display elements within my list. As you can see the checkbox is there, but I'm wondering how do I show/hide that checkbox depending on if the user presses a multi-select button within the Application Bar. Do I use a VisualStateManager? Do I hard code everything in and figure out a way to play an animation? I'm confused with Windows Phone 8's design methodology.

Comment: Try looking [at this sample code](http://pastebin.com/bjwkJf4L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the `MultiSelectList` from the [Windows Phone toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/), which can recreate the effect that you're looking for.

Information on how to use it is available from [this blog post](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-multiselectlist-in-depth--part1-key-concepts-and-api), or from the Samples that are included with the source code of the toolkit.

Comment: The `LongListMultiSelector` class is what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is set **EnforceIsSelectionEnabled** as true or false to show or hide the checkboxes using LongListMultiSelector