# How to select all checkBoxes in LongListMultiSelector WP8

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, checkbox

How can i select all the checkBoxes in LongListMultiSelector on click of a ApplicatonBar's ApplicationBarMenuItem. This feature is same as messaging app of wondows phone.
I reffered 
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685504/how-to-show-hide-with-animation-if-possible-a-checkbox-within-a-longlistselect/27553711#27553711)
but no use.

my code:

```
        <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector  x:Name="requestList" 
                    EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="False">
            <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="requestNameTxtblk" 
                     Text="{Binding request}"  
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     Width="268" Height="66"  FontSize="25"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys got the solution

```
        foreach (var item in requestList.ItemsSource)
        {
                requestList.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
```

this will check all the checkBox in the list and to uncheck all the box
Remove() method can be used as add()

Answer (score 0):

Can you just iterate over the `requestList`'s `ItemsSource` and mark the items as selected:

(note this code is not tested, just a guess for now):

```
foreach (var item in requestList.ItemsSource)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

Or similar?